# Error with date when publish Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, google-chrome, datetime

I have a selector where the name of a recipe appears, when you select one of them a gridview is completed. The gridview is completed with the date and time of each action.

If I test the website from the Visual Studio emulator, the date format in the gridview appears correct (it is the same in the database), the format is: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.

However, when I publish the website to access from IIS, the gridview is the same but the date format changed to: dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss.

I have looked at date formats in sql, windows date format, everything seems correct.

I have also tried filtering with a datetimepicker and it does pick up the format correctly.

Comment: A date has no format, it is just a number. You have to set the localization somewhere or specify the format of the date.

Comment: My question is where to enter that. If when running from visual studio it looks good, and then when running from the server it changes, I understand that the code is fine and, as you say, it is a problem of localization. I have tried adding the globalization tag with culture="es-ES" but it remains the same